# Open 'undo-tree-visualize side by side to the buffer, and not "vertically"

Tags: plugins, emacs, undo-redo

Is there any way I can make [undo-tree-mode](http://www.dr-qubit.org/undo-tree/undo-tree.el) display the visualization in a "horizontal" buffer (ie. C-x 3 vs. C-x 2)?

[image: What I want](![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `undo-tree` package uses standard Emacs buffer display functions to show the tree window (as opposed to a specific function).  To control how Emacs splits windows, you can customize the variables `split-window-preferred-function`, `split-height-threshold`, and `split-width-threshold`.  Also check out the documentation for the function `split-window-sensibly`.

If you are OK with Emacs in general preferring side-by-side windows over top-and-bottom ones, put this code in your init file:

```
(setq split-height-threshold 0)
```

(If you want side-by-side windows only for `undo-tree-visualize`, the story is a little more complicated.)

Comment: If it is needed only for undo tree then the variable can be set temporarily in an advice wrapped around the undo-tree-visualize function.

Comment: @Tom I would give you an upvote if you write the code snippet for that advice in an answer ;)

Comment: @DanielDinnyes I know it's a year and a half later, but you can check my answer for that code snippet. :)

Answer (score 7):

As per @Tom's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225054/open-undo-tree-visualize-side-by-side-to-the-buffer-and-not-vertically#comment8688073_7226580), I whipped up a solution that applies only to undo-tree:

```lisp
(defadvice undo-tree-visualize (around undo-tree-split-side-by-side activate)
  "Split undo-tree side-by-side"
  (let ((split-height-threshold nil)
        (split-width-threshold 0))
  ad-do-it))
```

**2017-04-29**: `defadvice` is now deprecated in favour of `advice-add`. The updated version of the solution above would be the following:

```lisp
(defun undo-tree-split-side-by-side (original-function &rest args)
  "Split undo-tree side-by-side"
  (let ((split-height-threshold nil)
        (split-width-threshold 0))
    (apply original-function args)))

(advice-add 'undo-tree-visualize :around #'undo-tree-split-side-by-side)
```